# Anchors - Links within a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I implement anchors in Rails views?
Something like this:

```
<a href="#someId">click</a>
<a id="someId"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rails helper method `link_to`, which can generate links, pointing to anchors. For example:

```
<%= link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall") %>
```

Here `:anchor` is an option of the path. It produces the following HTML:

```
<a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

Have a look at [the rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for further reading (it is a pretty long text, search for 'anchor')

I don't know of a helper method to generate the actual anchor. So you just put the plain HTML into your view:

```
<a name="wall">This is a Comment wall</a>
```

Comment: Thanks und Grüße auch aus Berlin;-)

Answer (score 0):

For simple anchors:

```
<%= link_to "Text", "Path" %>
```

Example:

```
<%= link_to "About Us", "/about-us" %>
```

You could always just use the HTML if you're not going to have Rails generate links:

```
<a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
```